# How to reload values in com.google.common.base.Supplier on demand

Tags: java, caching, java-8

I have a Supplier defined as below in one the Services. This supplier loads some values from database.

```
private final Supplier<Map<CustomClass1, CustomClass2>> sampleSupplier = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(getSampleSupplier(), 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

I want to reload values in this supplier on demand so that if database is updated within the Time Duration(1 Day), those values will be reloaded into the Supplier. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Mark `sampleSupplier` as volatile and replace it with a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is achievable via memoization, you need a cache instead from guava. It has methods that explicitly invalidate a key. So you would need a database trigger/listener that catches the event of when some entry changes and when that happens call:

```
 Cache.invalidate(key)
```

and then

```
cache.put(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could de-scope the supplier by re-assinging it?

```
pattern = Suppliers.memoize(() -> { return 1; });

pattern.get() == 1
pattern.get() == 1
pattern.get() == 1

pattern = Suppliers.memoize(() -> { return 2; });

pattern.get() == 2
pattern.get() == 2
```